# Netlogo Call observer context function in turtle context

Tags: netlogo

I want to do something for 20 ticks, but only if 2 turtles (different breeds and shapes) are on the same patch. However, what I want to do involves observer context items. If there any way possible to allow an observer function to be called in a turtle context function? Help is appreciated. Thanks! (players is a breed)

```
  to function1
      ask turtles with [shape = "car"]
         [if any? players-here [shieldTurtle]]
    end

    to shieldTurtle
      let startTicks ticks
      if ticks <= (startTicks + 20)
         [stop randomKill
          stop randomDamage
          stop randomSpeed]
    end
```

Comment: perhaps this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23474481/86485

Comment: Could you approach the problem a different way by passing information between functions. For example, create a boolean global variable (say want-to-stop?) and have the randomKill etc include `if want-to-stop? stop'. Then you could simply 'set want-to-stop? true' in your function1.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Seth's suggestion:

```
turtles-own [start-shield]

to setup
  ask turtles [set start-shield -20]
end 

to function1
  ask turtles with [shape = "car"] [
    if any? players-here [shieldTurtle]
  ]
end

to shieldTurtle
  set start-shield ticks
end

to randomKill ;;turtle proc
  if (ticks - start-shield < 20) [stop] ;;shielded turtle exits
  doThis
  doThat
end
```

etc.